# Drag & drop files upload multiple with preview before upload - php, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="dragdrop">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
</div>

<div class="preview">
   <src class="image-1" href="" alt="" />
   <src class="image-2" href="" alt="" />
   <src class="image-3" href="" alt="" />
    ???
</div>
```

I'm looking for a simple drag & drop, not to be too complicated.I do not know how you can preview images, after the addition.

Also, if you click on an image, it must be the top priority.

```
$priority = $_POST['image-2'];
```

Thanks!

**P.S.:** 
I check this, but no multiple: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ELcf6/4/)

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm)

Comment: This is after the upload status. I do not what I need. But thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "Also, if you click on an image, it must be the top priority"?

Comment: @Programer, sorry I didn't understood what are you trying to say

Comment: if click "image-1", then "image-1" will be the primary later.
This will be the first image in the gallery or etc...
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 3):

Here is your solution:-

Make a test.php file and run this code. It will allow you to upload multiple files and you can preview them.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input multiple="1" onchange="readURL(this);" id="uploadedImages" name="pictures[]" type="file">
  <div id ="up_images"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var readURL = function(input) {
      $('#up_images').empty();   
      var number = 0;
      $.each(input.files, function(value) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
              var id = (new Date).getTime();
              number++;
              $('#up_images').prepend('<img id='+id+' src='+e.target.result+' width="100px" height="100px" data-index='+number+' onclick="removePreviewImage('+id+')"/>')
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[value]);
          }); 
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you :)